# Wordpress: graphics not appearing on single post only

Tags: php, css, wordpress

My site has suddenly started not showing featured content graphics or my logo on single post pages, however shows normally on all other pages.

For example this page shows the logo top left: http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/news/
and this page doesn't: http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/big-brother-2014-housemates-first-impressions/

Also, on the second link, the 'Related Posts' area near the bottom was previously 4 images with wording below them.

This has happened on it's own. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<?php global $data ?>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>"/>

    <title><?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> </title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php if(is_rtl()) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Lioit_URI; ?>/rtl.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } else {?>

<?php }?>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<?php if(!empty($data['custom_favicon'])) { ?><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo $data['custom_favicon']; ?>" /><?php } ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php echo stripslashes($data['code_header']); ?>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php require Lioit_TM . '/css.php';?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/themes/liomagazine/ddimgtooltip.css" />

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/themes/liomagazine/ddimgtooltip.js">

<?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>
<style> .mainWidgets { margin-top:-363px !important} </style>
<?php }; ?>


/***********************************************
* Image w/ description tooltip v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/
</script>



<!-- BEGIN Tynt Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.location.protocol=='http:'){
 var Tynt=Tynt||[];Tynt.push('dZ977cXJir44ASacwqm_6r');
 (function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.async="async";s.type="text/javascript";s.src='http://tcr.tynt.com/ti.js';var h=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);})();
}
</script>
<!-- END Tynt Script -->

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php if($data['theme_width'] == 'fixed') { ?>
    <div id="fixedContainer">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="container">
    <?php }?>
            <div id="header" class="loadSmooth">

  <div id="logo">
<?php if($data['custom_logo'] !='') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php echo $data['custom_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php echo Lioit_IMG; ?>/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <?php } ?>
                                    </div><!--End Logo-->

<div id="banner">
<center>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www2.glam.com/app/site/affiliate/viewChannelModule.act?mName=viewAdJs&affiliateId=1648491755&adSize=728x90"></script> 

</center>

</div>

<div id="content" class="loadSmooth">

 <!--End Banner-->



        </div><!--End Main Header-->
        </div><!--End Header-->


        <div class="topBar loadSmooth">
             <div class="inner">
<div id="hmbar">
<div style="padding-left:0px; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: 18px;">
</div>
<div style="margin: -50px auto auto -3px; position: static; width: 990px; ">

<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/ash-harrison/" rel="imgtip[15]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/ASH%20HARRISON.png" style="margin-top:4px"  alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/ashleigh-coyle/" rel="imgtip[13]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/ASHLEIGH%20COYLE.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/mark-byron/" rel="imgtip[2]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/MARK%20BYRON.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/helen-wood/" rel="imgtip[3]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/HELEN%20WOOD.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/new-housemate-pavandeep-paul-profile/">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/PAVANDEEP-PAUL.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/steven-goode/" rel="imgtip[4]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/STEVEN%20GOODE.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/winston-showan/" rel="imgtip[6]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/WINSTON%20SHOWAN.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/christopher-hall/" rel="imgtip[9]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/CHRISTOPHER%20HALL.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/chris-r-wright/" rel="imgtip[12]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/CHRIS%20R%20WRIGHT.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/tamara-steward-wood/" rel="imgtip[1]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/TAMARA%20STEWART-WOOD%20evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href=" http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/danielle-mcmahon/" rel="imgtip[5]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/DANIELLE-McMAHON-evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/matthew-davies/" rel="imgtip[7]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/MATTHEW%20DAVIES evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href=" http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/kimberly-kisselovich/" rel="imgtip[8]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/KIMBERLY-KISSELOVICH-evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/pauline-bennett/" rel="imgtip[10]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/Housemates/PAULINE%20BENNETT%20evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/toya-washington/" rel="imgtip[11]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/TOYA-A-WASHINGTON-EVICTED.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/marlon-wallen/ " rel="imgtip[14]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/MARLON-WALLEN-evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/jale-karaturp/" rel="imgtip[16]">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/JALE-KARATURP-evicted.png" alt="Housemate"></a>
</div></div>
<nav>
                <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'mainmenu' ) ) { ?>
                <?php  wp_nav_menu ( array( 'menu_id' => 'topNavigation','container'=> '', 'theme_location' => 'mainmenu' )); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                  <ul id="topNavigation">
                     <li class="active <?php if (is_home()) {echo "current_page_item";} ?>"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="home"><?php _e('Home' , 'lioit' ) ?></a></li>
                     <?php wp_list_pages(array(
                    'title_li' => false
                  )); ?>
                  </ul>

                <?php } ?>
                </nav>
                <div class="topRss">   
                    <?php if(!empty($data['social_header'])) { ?>
                    <?php require Lioit_TM . '/social.php';?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div><!--End topRss-->
            </div><!--End Top Bar Content-->
        </div><!--End TopBar-->

        <div id="mainNavigation" class="navigation loadSmooth">
            <div class="inner">
                <nav class="primary container">
                    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'mainnav' ) ) { ?>
                       <?php  wp_nav_menu ( array( 'menu_id' => 'dropmenu','container'=> 'ul', 'theme_location' => 'mainnav' )); ?>
                       <?php } else { ?>
                          <ul id="dropmenu">
                             <li class="<?php if (is_home()) {echo "current_page_item";} ?> home"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php _e('Home' , 'lioit' ) ?></a></li>
                             <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=');?>
                          </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                </nav>

        </div><!--End Main Menu--></div><!--End Main Menu-->


<div id="pushdown" style="margin:0 auto; width:970px;"> 

 <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www2.glam.com/app/site/affiliate/viewChannelModule.act?mName=viewAdJs&affiliateId=1648491755&adSize=970x66"> </script> 
</div>            

        <div id="content" class="loadSmooth">
        <?php if( is_front_page()) { ?>
        <?php if($data['disable_top_bar'] != '0') { ?>

        <div class="notification ondemand hide">

            <?php if(!empty($data['note'])) { ?>
                <p><?php echo $data['note']; ?><a href="<?php echo $data['note_url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $data['note_text']; ?></a></p>
            <?php } ?>
            <a class="close" href="javascript:">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon-close.png" />
            </a>

        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($data['newsticker'] != '0') { 
             require Lioit_TM . '/ticker.php';
         } else { 
         } ?>
        <?php require Lioit_TM . '/top.search.php';?>
```

The code which creates the related content:

```
<?php if(!empty($data['show_related'])) { ?>
                     <?php require Lioit_TM . '/related.php';?>

                <?php } ?>
```

The database errors

```
wp_users: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
wp_usermeta: 4 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_posts: 5 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_comments: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_options: 8 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_postmeta: 8 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_terms: 4 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_term_taxonomy: 4 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_term_relationships: 4 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_commentmeta: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
```

Comment: Have you recently updated theme?

Comment: Hi @Stewartside, no I haven't. No changes have been made.

Comment: What does the contents of header.php actually look like? There is no way of helping without seeing the code. I wont comment on the subject of the site!

Comment: @user574632 well the header.php is the same for all pages across the site, however on single post pages it blocks the logo from even loading in the css, as well as the featured images of the random posts at the bottom.

Comment: **Please show the code**, there will be some code somewhere that causes this (unless your webserver is haunted), but nobody can guess what it is

Comment: The code has already been added into the main description. @user574632

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything from `id="logo"` to `<!--End Logo-->` with the below if it still does not work then the page is using  different template.

```
<div id="logo">
<a href="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/" title="Totally Big Brother 2014 UK on Channel 5" rel="home">
<img src="http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/logomobile1.png" alt="Totally Big Brother 2014 UK on Channel 5">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Whilst that gives a quick fix to the logo problem, that doesn't fix the problem of the featured images. It seems something has just randomly caused this fault. http://totallybigbrother.co.uk/kimberly-reveals-true-feelings-steven-bbbots-interview/ < go to the bottom, above the comments where it says Related Posts that should be 4 images as here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:18t0k6qQC7kJ:totallybigbrother.co.uk/daley-has-been-removed-from-the-big-brother-house/+&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a < cached version

Comment: Then I would start with the basic wordpress debugging methods, first set debug to true in the wp-config http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php. If nothing shows up then I would disable and then move all plugins out of the wp-content/plugins folder to another location to see if one is causing a problem. Also has the server been updated what version of PHP are you running on has this changed? Have you tried to repair your database?

Comment: Hey @user1983834 I did a debug and nothing at all, no PHP errors and the server hasn't had any problems. However, when I did a repair of the database I found a number of errors which I have added into the description, however the repair tool wasn't able to fix any.

Comment: I was able to get the repair tool to fix these however the problem still remains!

Comment: Hello, well it looks like the problem is the database. I find that database corruption usually happens when the environmental space is running low, such as ram or disk space. Are you able to do a restore using a backup of the database?

Can you add `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` to your wp-config file this may help in future. and add `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` this may help to shield from further coruption

Comment: Also if you cannot roll back the database then I would try this in SSH/Terminal.
`myisamchk --check /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --analyze /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --recover /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --update-state /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --correct-checksum /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --sort-recover  /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --sort-index  /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
myisamchk --extend-check /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI;
mysqlcheck --analyse --all-databases;
mysqlcheck --optimize --all-databases;
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases;
service mysqld restart;`

Comment: Just to mention I am getting error 500 Internal Server Error when trying to view the website

Comment: Hi There, I am getting the same error all of a sudden, so not sure what I can do to resolve this. I have container backups for Paralells but that is it

Comment: At this point I would consider restoring all files including WordPress via FTP to make sure there is no corruption. Check the server error_logs, both apache, the site error log and mysql log located in www/logs and any error logs in the top level of the site directory.

I would consider paying an expert to diagnose your problem, there are plenty of website that offer freelancer services